# How can I pass arguments to the makedepend calls made by cmake?

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, dependencies

Is there a way to pass command arguments/options to the `makedepend` calls made during a `cmake` generated `make` build?

I'd like to pass a `-D` argument to `makedepend` so that certain `#include`s are *ignored* because they're hidden by conditionals that are always false for this build.

Here's a motivating minimal example.

In `A.cpp`:

```
#include "B.h"
int main(){}
```

In `B.h`:

```
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H
void B();
#ifndef NOT_HEADER_ONLY
#  include "B.cpp"
#endif
#endif
```

In `B.cpp`:

```
#include "B.h"
void B(){}
```

In `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.6)
option(NOT_HEADER_ONLY "Off")
set(SRCFILES "A.cpp")
if(NOT_HEADER_ONLY)
  add_definitions(-DNOT_HEADER_ONLY)
  list(APPEND SRCFILES "B.cpp")
endif()
add_executable(A ${SRCFILES})
```

If I build using:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -DNOT_HEADER_ONLY=Off
make
```

Only `A.cpp` is compiled directly (as expected) and if I `touch B.cpp` then `A.cpp` will be triggered for re-compilation (as expected).

If *instead* I use:

```
cmake .. -DNOT_HEADER_ONLY=On
make
```

the dependences are *too conservative* in the sense that they will never miss the dependency, but if `B.cpp` is touched then `A.cpp` is triggered for re-compilation despite the `#include "B.cpp"` inside `B.h` being hidden by `#ifndef NOT_HEADER_ONLY` (since `NOT_HEADER_ONLY` is defined).

I realize that that some other file could `#undef NOT_HEADER_ONLY` causing `B.cpp` to become a true dependency of `B.h` but I want to assume this never happens. It seems that `makedepend`'s `-D` option is readymade for this. Indeed `makedepend -DNOT_HEADER_ONLY A.cpp` outputs:

```
# DO NOT DELETE

A.o: B.h
```

But how do I tell cmake to use `makedepend -DNOT_HEADER_ONLY` instead of just `makedepend`?

(I'd even be happy to hack cmake's autogenerated `Makefile`s but I can't locate the `makedepend` calls).

Comment: This post seems to suggest that cmake ignores `#if` directives http://cmake.3232098.n2.nabble.com/C-C-dependency-scanner-td4760539.html, but I previously understood that cmake was calling `makedepend` is that not true?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm hunting in the right place, but looking at the [cmake source](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/3d3d3f94703e23d3d2cbff67537057474e3e0ff1/Source/cmDependsC.cxx) it seems that dependencies are determined by matching a regex on `#include` lines (not via a call to `makedepend`).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pretty extreme hack that will work in this case but might be hard to generalize or might have hidden effects.

Instead of issuing:

```
make
```

Issue:

```
mkdir -p CMakeFiles/A.dir/hole
makedepend -DNOT_HEADER_ONLY -pCMakeFiles/A.dir/hole/  -o .cpp.o -f - ../A.cpp ../B.cpp -w0 > CMakeFiles/A.dir/depend.make
make -f CMakeFiles/A.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/A.dir/build
```

This creates a dummy folder (so `../` will make sense), then calls `makedepend` directly instead of letting `cmake` determine dependencies, then calls the actual build `make` command directly.